# slick auto-generated Models in sourceManaged folder: how to access them in a Controller?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, slick-codegen

in play 2.5, I am using the slick codegenerator from com.typesafe.slick   `"com.typesafe.slick"  %%  "slick-codegen"  %  "3.1.1" % "compile"` and it works fine: the  auto-generated Slick data model is generated to the file `target/scala-2.11/src_managed/slick/dao/Tables.scala`.

My question: how can I access the generated Models and TableQuery objects from a Controller, let's say `app/controllers/myDAOController.scala` ? Any hints or a working example would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
import Tables._
```

in your Controller. 
You will be able to use all your models.

Example:
Here is your table:

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS "COMPANIES" ("ID" INTEGER NOT NULL,"NAME" VARCHAR NOT NULL);
```

You will access the generated Companies model like this:

```
val myCompanyName = Companies.filter(_.id === 10).map(_.name)
```

See a complete example here : https://github.com/slick/slick-codegen-example/blob/master/src/main/scala/Example.scala

Comment: Did you set your build.sbt file as described here ? https://github.com/slick/slick-codegen-example/blob/master/build.sbt

Comment: I am using the activator UI for developing. In the controller `app/controllers/myDAOController.scala` I declare the `package controllers`. The statement `ìmport Tables._` yields an compile error: not found: `object Tables`. What would be the full path for Tables._ ?

Comment: The build.sbt is exactly the same as outlined in your example, wwith the only difference that I use mySQL.

Comment: Do you see Tables.scala file in `target/scala-2.11/src_managed/slick/`?

Comment: Yes, the Tables.scala file is correctly generated, and located in `target/scala-2.11/src_managed/slick/dao/` .  Omitting the folder 'dao' does not help.

Comment: Try to put the `Tables.scala` file into `app/slick` folder for example (and change your import in Controller to `import slick.Tables._`). Or change `outputDir` value in `build.sbt` to `outputDir = ((sourceDirectory in Compile).value).getPath`